# Can't get rid of navigability issues caused by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in `python` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` to parse a certain address from a webpage. However, when i run my below script I get an issue `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'` when it hits the line `address = [item.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)`. I can get rid of this issue if I try the commented out lines. However, I would like to stick to the way that is currently applied. What can I do so ?

This is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/officers/lX9snXUPL09h7ljtMYLdZU9LmOo/appointments"

def fetch_names(session,link):
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#content-container dt"):

        #the error appears in the following line

        address = [item.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True) for item in items if "correspondence address" in item.text.lower()][0]
        print(address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        fetch_names(session,URL)
```

I can get rid of the error by doing something like below but i wanna stick to the way I tried in my script:

```
items = soup.select("#content-container dt")
address = [item.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True) for item in items if "correspondence address" in item.text.lower()][0]
print(address)
```

> ### EDIT:
>
> It's not an answer but this is how I tried to play around (still unsure how to apply `.find_previous_sibling()` though:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/officers/lX9snXUPL09h7ljtMYLdZU9LmOo/appointments"

def fetch_names(session,link):
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#content-container dt"):
        address = [item for item in items.strings if "correspondence address" in item.lower()]
        print(address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        fetch_names(session,URL)
```

And it produces(no navigability issues).

```
[]
['Correspondence address']
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `items` is not a list of nodes, but a single node, so you should not use it as iterator here - `for item in items`. Just replace list comprehension with below:

```
for items in soup.select("#content-container dt"):
    if "correspondence address" in items.text.lower():
        address = items.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
        print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your BeautifulSoup selector to look directly for the contact address id to #correspondence-address-value-1.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/officers/lX9snXUPL09h7ljtMYLdZU9LmOo/appointments"

def fetch_names(session,link):
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    addresses = [a.text for a in soup.select("#correspondence-address-value-1")]
    print(addresses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        fetch_names(session,URL)
```

Results

```
13:32 $ python test.py
['21 Maes Y Llan, Conwy, Wales, LL32 8NB']
```

Comment: That won't be a good idea cause you are dealing with a partial portion of my giant script in which there are multiple searches and few search result may not contain that field that is why I avoided using "ID" in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Then drop the list comprehension and use a for loop instead with the same conditions. Wrap the  .get_text() part (which throws the error - apparently not all element can be called with .get_text()) in a try/except block. And that should do it.